# A city where it doesn't rain in the day, for a month, and can farm on the outskirts

Tags: environment, geography, weather

I'm trying to figure out if a certain city, with these characteristics, is possible, geographically:

- Assume the city's the size of Renaissance London...
- With Renaissance London technology
- Doesn't precipitate (rain or snow) in the daytime, for about one and a half months.
- Has farms outside the city and can farm wheat, oranges, apples, walnuts, and (sugar cane or sugar beets or some other source of sugar for pastry and other confectioneries).
- The populace doesn't need any special clothing to prevent heatstroke. They wear the clothes of commoners of Renaissance England. (No desert people clothing...)
- There's a river running through the middle of the city.
- The rest of the surrounding area can be anything you want.

Comment: Irrigation would solve this easily.

Comment: This is almost an exact description of coastal California, except maybe for the sugarcane.  There should also be similar places on the Mediterranean.

Comment: You might want to replace sugar cane with sugar beets as the later grows in temperate climates.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Also the Central Valley (again excepting the sugarcane).  Though most crops are irrigated, it's perfectly possible to do e.g. dryland wheat farming.  I know this because at one point in my life I spent many hours driving tractors around those fields.

Comment: @jamesqf: Yeah, I first thought of Sacramento, but thought its summer high temperatures around 33 C on average might risk heatstroke for inhabitants (point 4).

Comment: erm... what that city doing there? Oh I see its a colony from Mars 1 damn should get a better telescope next time.

Comment: Can you define the timeframe for us?  In Abu Dhabi, where it didn't rain for five years straight, desal is used for their drive toward better self-sufficiency in food products.  Other places could pump water from a river or aquifer.  But I suspect you want much older technology levels.

Comment: @Mikey - Renaissance London in area, population, and tech level... I removed the tech level from my initial post 'cause I thought it was irrelevant... Obviously not!

Comment: @Malandy ah, saw your edit.  Thanks for clarification; I'll give it a think - cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify your specific point of "doesn't rain in the day" and "can rain at night"? I can't see any reason why plants would need day-time rain. Looks to me that if it rains the usual amount, but only after dark, there would be no problem at all. In fact, you'd be optimising the daylight.  As to HOW it would only rain at night, I have no idea.

Comment: @Cylindric - Oh... those were suggestions for answerers, of how to work around plants that need rain, but due to the "Doesn't rain/snow", can't get the water from the daytime... Gonna rework that sentence to use "Doesn't precipitate in the daytime..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem I see is with your listed crops. Sugarcane and oranges are subtropical/tropical crops, while apples, wheat, and walnuts are all temperate crops. There are some pretty big differences between the ideal growing conditions of those crops.

Example: sugarcane requires a lot of moisture, but walnut trees do poorly in wet soils. And if it's hot enough to support sugarcane the apple trees probably won't get the winter dormancy period they need to thrive. Subtropical crops don't tolerate frost well at all, either.

Is it possible to grow all of those crops in one place? Maybe, but it would be a lot of extra work to manage whichever crops are disadvantaged by the natural climate in the area. You can grow oranges in temperate regions, for instance, but you have to bring them inside in winter. That's fine if you have one or two small trees in pots, but not practical for a large orchard.

I'd say pick whatever climate you want and choose crops that all grow in that climate for cultivation around the city. If you really want those specific crops, you could say your city climate is fine for growing oranges, sugarcane, and other subtropical/tropical crops, but adjacent high elevation territory (a high plateau, for example), drier and colder in winter, is where your temperate crops are cultivated.

Answer (score 7):

Western California is a lot like this.  Consider for example the city of [Santa Rosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Rosa,_California):

- Current population: about 175,000, comparable to London circa 1575 according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_London#Population)
- Average precipitation in July is 0.8 mm.  It would not be unusual to go for many years with no measurable rainfall in July.  There is typically only minimal rainfall between June and September.
- Agriculture is a major part of the economy.  Currently the most prominent crop is grapes, but apples and walnuts are grown commercially in the vicinity.  I don't think oranges are grown there on a large scale these days, but many people have orange trees in their yards which produce fruit with a little care (they may need to be covered to protect them from occasional winter frost).  Not sure about wheat but I have seen corn (maize), and wild grasses cover most of the uncultivated land, so I would assume grain crops are generally an option.  Sugar cane may be a stretch, though, as I would think it's more of a tropical crop.  You could grow sugar beets, if you want; Santa Rosa is in [USDA Hardiness Zone 8](http://planthardiness.ars.usda.gov/PHZMWeb/InteractiveMap.aspx), which according to [this site](http://www.almanac.com/plant/beets) should be suitable for sugar beets.
- Average summer high temperature of 28 C.  Heatstroke not a concern.
- The Santa Rosa Creek runs through the city.  If you want a larger waterway, relocate the city 30 km north to the site of [Healdsburg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healdsburg,_California), on the [Russian River](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_River_%28California%29).

So in general your description seems very plausible, if you tweak your sugar crop a little.

Comment: Well, the sugar cane isn't that huge a part of my question, but I'm not gonna change the question, 'cause that would invalidate some answers... and, as the primary purpose of sugar cane is the sugar... then *sugar* beets are absolutely an acceptable substitute... ... If you want to edit the question and feel like taking that risk... go ahead!

Comment: Welcome to the site Nate! Great answer!

Comment: Wait... I just looked at the map... What kind of geography makes such a coastal city have almost no rain?!

Comment: @Malandy: There is rain, about 75 cm per year, just not in the summer.  You can read meteorological details on the Wikipedia page for [Mediterranean climate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediterranean_climate): "During summer, regions of Mediterranean climate are dominated by subtropical high pressure cells, with dry sinking air capping a surface marine layer of varying humidity and making rainfall impossible or unlikely..."

Comment: @Malandy: Much of the western US is like this (except the northern coast west of the Cascades).  Almost all of the precipitation comes in the winter months.  In summer, all you'll usually get are a few thunderstorms over the Sierra Nevada and eastwards.

Comment: There is a lot of rain actually, except for three months of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Such a city could easily exist inside a desert which has a river flowing through it. Being a desert doesn't mean there is no water, it just means there is little to no precipitation. The city of [Calama, Chile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calama,_Chile) is in the Atacama desert.

- It has a river running through it.
- It gets about [one inch of rain per year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calama,_Chile#Geography_and_Climate) and most of that occurs
  in a single month.
- The average high temperature every month doesn't get over 76°F.
- There are not a lot of farms, but they likely could be built and irrigated from the river.

If you base your city on Calama then the conditions you're asking for are entirely feasible.